# XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING cannot be disabled

Tags: java, xml, dom

In the following method I defined a DocumentBuilderFactory with the XMLConstant `FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING` as false.

```
private static DocumentBuilderFactory getDocumentBuilderFactory() throws ParserConfigurationException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, false);
    factory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, ""); // Compliant
    factory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, ""); // compliant
    return factory;
}
```

However, when I test the value of this property, it is 'true' after the DocumentBuilderFactory is returned.

I read the source documentation, and it states:

> It is possible for an {@code TransformerFactory} to expose a feature
> value but be unable to change its state.

I am assuming this property is "unchangeable" by simply setting it to false. I am curious, is it possible to use Reflection to get around this? Are there any other more "stable" ways of setting this property to false?

Comment: Let's say you could use reflection and set it to false.  Do you think that the underlying implementation would respect this setting?  Presumably it doesn't allow it to be set because it doesn't support it.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Likely something like "if (value == false), value = true; Hypothetically I could override the method itself via reflection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING` cannot be turned off, unfortunately. You can effectively override this security measure by adjusting the limits associated with `FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING`.

Example via System Properties:

```
    final String MAX_XPATH_GROUP_LIMIT = "jdk.xml.xpathExprGrpLimit";
    final String MAX_XPATH_OPERATOR_LIMIT = "jdk.xml.xpathExprOpLimit";
    final String MAX_XPATH_TOTAL = "jdk.xml.xpathTotalOpLimit";

        System.setProperty(MAX_XPATH_GROUP_LIMIT, "-1");
        System.setProperty(MAX_XPATH_OPERATOR_LIMIT, "-1");
        System.setProperty(MAX_XPATH_TOTAL, "-1");
```

Values <= 0 are equivalent to 'no limit'.

Source: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-0-15-relnotes.html

Comment: Could you explain why you say these limits are associated with `FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING`?  I have seen error messages from the JDK that relate the two, but those release notes strongly suggest that these limits are _always_ in place (and therefore that this 8u331 / 11.0.15 / ... change is a breaking change even if secure processing is not enabled).